# how to display information related to clicked element in next page using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT client_id, firm_name FROM savedata";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> Client_id: ". $row["client_id"]. "<br> <a href ='view.php'>Client Name: ". $row["firm_name"]." </a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I am using this code for display my client name from my database,I want to display all the information related to clicked client in view.php.

Thank you

Comment: You can pass the ID through the URL: `<a href ='view.php?id=" . $row['client_id'] . "'>`. Then in the `view.php` page, you can get the ID with: `$id = $_GET['id']`. Now you can fetch that specific user from the database based in the ID.

Comment: Thank u so much sir,it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code

```
echo "<br> Client_id: ". $row["client_id"]. "<br> <a href ='view.php'>Client Name: ". $row["firm_name"]." </a>";
```

to

```
echo "<br> Client_id: ". $row["client_id"]. "<br> <a href ='view.php?cid=".$row["client_id"]."'>Client Name: ". $row["firm_name"]." </a>";
```

Then in view.php

```
$sql = "SELECT client_id, firm_name FROM savedata where client_id=".$_GET['cid'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<br> Client_id: ". $row["client_id"]. "<br> Client Name: ". $row["firm_name"];
 }
```

Comment: **Warning:** This code is _wide open_ to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating raw and unescaped user data like that! Never ever ever never trust user data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href ='view.php?clientId=".$row["client_id"]."'>Client Name: ". $row["firm_name"]." </a>
```

view.php:

```
if(isset($_GET[`clientId`]) {
    $clientId=$_GET[`clientId`];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM savedata WHERE id=`$clientId`";
    ....
}else{
    ...
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** This code is _wide open_ to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of injecting raw and unescaped user data like that! Never ever ever never trust user data.